# getting "java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute `conda info` exited with 1" when using anaconda on Apache Zeppelin

Tags: python, conda, cloudera, apache-zeppelin

I am using Cloudera VM with Apache Zeppelin
For one time-series project I had to install Anaconda parcel because I needed some python packages (Pandas and FBProhet).

It works fine if I use `%spark.pyspark` interpreter and point my python binary to `/home/oracle/.conda/envs/prophet/bin/python` (this is the conda environment with pandas and prophet)

But when I use python interpreter instead of spark, I get the following error: (when you use anaconda, you have to activate the environment you need)

```
%python.conda info

java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute `conda info` exited with 1
    at org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonCondaInterpreter.runCommand(PythonCondaInterpreter.java:412)
    [...]
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

zeppelin.python  to the python binary to certain environment, but I should be able to make it work with python environment and be able to switch to another environment without changing environment variables or Zeppelin settings.

If I set the following variables in zeppelin-env.sh it works fine:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/oracle/.conda/envs/prophet/bin/python
export PYTHONPATH=/home/oracle/.conda/envs/prophet/bin
```

But they should point to a neutral path:

```
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin/python
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/bin
```

But in this case, it doesn't work, because interpreter cannot find the needed libraries (Pandas, FBProphet, etc.)

According to the [official documentation](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/python.html#conda), the following line is the first one in one Zeppelin notebook

```
%python.conda info
```

which gives the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to execute `conda info` exited with 1
    at org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonCondaInterpreter.runCommand(PythonCondaInterpreter.java:412)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonCondaInterpreter.runCondaCommandForTextOutput(PythonCondaInterpreter.java:180)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonCondaInterpreter.runCondaInfo(PythonCondaInterpreter.java:263)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.python.PythonCondaInterpreter.interpret(PythonCondaInterpreter.java:108)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:103)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:632)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:188)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I expect to be able to switch among anaconda environments when using python as Zeppelin interpreter

[image: error when executing %python.conda info]